# VMWare Fusion Linux Ubuntu not recognizing mac OS, asking to erase disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, macos, vmware-fusion

Im trying to install Ubuntu on my virtual machine, VMWare Fusion. I'm running version 12.2.5, and I downloaded the .iso file for ubuntu for version 23.4 here: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

I used the add/insert disk option to add the new machine such as:

[image]

[image]

After doing this, a window for the ubuntu virtual machine pops ups and asks me to set it up until it gets to a point where it cannot recognized an operating system and asks me to erase the disk:

[image]

I believe its not a great idea to erase the disk since I assume the disk in question is my mac's.

What should I do about this?

I tried to do the "something else" option, which gives me this:

[image]

I have no idea what that is.

If its not too much to ask, please give me instructions. I've read a bunch of resources online and I was still not able to figure this out.

Please, HELP!!!!

Thanks

Comment: I figured it all. Its ok to do it, it referes to the virtual machine only. This question can be closed.